# How do you insert a line into a file at a specific line number?

Tags: php, html

In PHP there is fopen('r+') for Read/Write. (start at beginning of the file) 
There is also fopen('a+') for Read/Write. (append to the end of the file)

I made a simple $_POST['data'] form that writes whatever is written in the form to a file. My problem is that if I write a few things, for example.

```
'Red ' 
'Green ' 
'Blue '
```

If I append this data, it will show up in the file in the order I write in.

But, I need to write to the beginning of the file, so that it's in reverse order.

```
'Blue '
'Green '
'Red '
```

$file_data = 'What to write in the file';

$file_data .= file_get_contents('testz.php');
file_put_contents('testz.php', $file_data);

1. This will write whatever is in the $file_data variable to the file and then write the data that was originally in the file afterwards.

Thus causing it to show up before everything else that was originally in the file. This works fine.

---

The problem starts when I want to include a line of code at the beginning of the file.

> Specifically I want '!DOCTYPE html html head' to always be at the
>   top of the document. I could of course put that in the file data like:
>   file_put_contents('testz.php', $headerinformation.$file_data);

But the problem with that is gonna be everytime I submit the POST, It's gonna be repeating

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>Blue
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>Green
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>Red
```

What I want is

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
Blue
Green
Red
```

So, then I can keep writing more information to the file via the POST form WITHOUT REPLACING THE FIRST LINE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
```

I know this is gonna be kind of a bad question, what what exactly can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe an `if` statement? Check if the first line is already in the file, before writing it again? Or, did I miss something?

Comment: So you managed to do some string concatenation once, but now you fail to do it a second time ...?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would implement that. The first line is already in the file, it's always going to be. I want it to be. The trick is to prevent php from writing it muliple times. I could do 'Header Information'.'Blah Blah Blah'.file_put_contents('file.php');

But I'm going to end up with multiple instances of the Header Information when I only need one to be at the beginning. So if I went with an if statement I would have to find a way to scan the document and remove all instance of it except the first, which wouldn't be very practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should write the first line at the time you create the file, e.g.:

```
$first_line = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>" . PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents("somefile.txt", $first_line);
```

And when you want to insert new content you could load your file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and insert the content at index 1 of the array (which is the second line in the file) by using [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
$lines = file("somefile.txt");
array_splice($lines, 1, 0, "new content");
```

Use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join the array elements to a string and finally write to the file:

```
$file_content = implode(PHP_EOL, $lines);
file_put_contents("somefile.txt", $file_content);
```

Note that this approach will lead to memory issues when dealing with large files.

Comment: Yesss! I realized that. I could just put whatever data I need there first, and then seek forward that amount of chars. But your solution is also very good, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can only add to the end of a file. You can write in the middle of it but only writing over existing data. So in order to add lines of text always as the second line you should load the data, add the line in the right place, then write the file again.

But I think what you are doing is a very weird thing to do, and most likely avoidable. You are writing an HTML file which makes me think you are going to display it at some point, in which case you should separate data handling and presentation.

For example you can treat the file as a data file where you just append lines without a header, then when you want to serve the data as html you output a header first and then the lines in reverse order.

Comment: You can write to the beginning by doing

fwrite($f, 'Beginning'.file_get_contents('File.php');

Comment: That approach is not prepending to the beginning of the file but rather rewriting the file with new data at the beginning. That is the approach I explain in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check if file is already with some data in it, for eg.:

```
$data_to_write = file_get_contents('testz.php'); 
$header_data = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>';
$file_data .= (empty($data_to_write))?$header_data.$data_to_write:$data_to_write;
file_put_contents('testz.php', $file_data);
```

Comment: Why do I need to do that? I already know there is data in it. I need to write more data to it before the already existing data while preserving the first line of data in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it this way,

```
<?php
$f=fopen('WriteFile.php', 'r+');
$W='<!DOCTYPE html>'.file_get_contents('WriteFile.php');
$S='New Data';
fwrite($f, "$W");
fgets($f);
fseek($f,15);
fwrite($f, "$S");
?>
```